# Need attribution of Spider-Man quote-Not everyone is meant to make a difference. But for me the choice to lead an ordinary life is no longer an option

Tags: story-identification, comics, spider-man, quotes, marvel

I need correct attribution of the quote "Not everyone is meant to make a difference. But for me the choice to lead an ordinary life is no longer an option." Was this only for the movie? Or did it come from an original Spider-Man issue?

Answer (score 5):

**As a long-term reader of Spider-Man this quotation did not seem to have a direct correlation in any particular issue of the comic (as far as my memory allows). The tone and tenor however resonate with the character's themes of self-reliance and personal responsibility.**

The quotation comes from Spider-Man (2002) and the screenplay was written by [David Koepp] referenced from the IMDB.

- Spider-Man is the quintessential self-made hero, he, unlike so many of the young Marvel heroes of his origin time period, was without a superheroic mentor and was forced to learn the other more famous mantras: "With great power, comes great responsibility."
- Unfortunately, he tended to learn most of his lessons regarding responsibility were at great personal cost (i.e. the deaths of Uncle Ben and Gwen Stacy, the failure of his marriage to Mary Jane, the creation of Venom(s) who were not his fault, but became his problem; etc...)

**Reference: Overthinking It - [The Cautionary Tale of Spider-Man](http://www.overthinkingit.com/2012/03/14/spider-man-cautionary-tale/)**